# How do I make a BTLE connection from Scratch

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, mit-scratch

I want to control a robot from the programming language Scratch but I have no clue how to make this happen. For now I'm running Scratch 1.4 on MacOS, and I can control the robot over BTLE using Swift or ObjC, but don't know where to go from here. The robot has a couple of motors (left/right wheels, head) and several sensors.

Do I need to write an extension in Python? A mod? Can I do this with Scratch 1.4 or do I need 2.0 (*hating Adobe Air*)?

Any useful pointers would be great!

Comment: Could you give more info on the robot? The only hardware accessories supported are PicoBoard and the Lego WeDos.

Comment: It is a Dash/Dot robot from MakeWonder. And/or a Sphere Ollie. I'd expect that I can write some extension or bridge to control the robots and have scratch talk to the bridge somehow...

Answer (score 0):

Consider a ScratchX (ScratchX.org) extension. They are implemented in JavaScript.